# react-native version:0.29.1 running in device throws unsupported file type

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native module 0.29.1, while running in device i am getting some error like this

```
    /Users/stlmini-1221/Desktop/POD/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: unsupported file type
    at lookup (/Users/stlmini-1221/Desktop/POD/node_modules/image-size/lib/index.js:35:9)
    at /Users/stlmini-1221/Desktop/POD/node_modules/image-size/lib/index.js:93:22
    at /Users/stlmini-1221/Desktop/POD/node_modules/image-size/lib/index.js:50:9
    at /Users/stlmini-1221/Desktop/POD/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:43:10
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

But in simulator it working fine,For this i tried many ways like this

```
<Image source={{uri: 'something.jpg'}} />
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
<Image source={{uri: 'something.jpg'}} />
<Image  source={require('image!help')}/>
```

Instead of png changed to jpg but still i can't resolve my issue any one give me suggestion that how to solve this any help my appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got this error. I removed special characters from my file name and after that it worked.
You can try to rename your my-icon.png file as MyIcon.png and after that use it like this

```
<Image source={require('./MyIcon.png')} />
```